# Retina Image show 1/4th size in cocos2d ios6

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, ios6

i researched so much about that but i cant find anything interesting..  actually i had a project in cocos2d made in ios5 and show images size good either in retina .. when upgraded to ios6 it shows one fourth image sizes..  It shows Retina display ON in CCDirector.

Comment: Step into CCFileUtils where the image is loaded. Perhaps the -hd file simply wasn't found?

Comment: I had check in CCFileUtils it picking up the with -hd. Also checked without -hd picking up center as top right corner as sprite center position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think this will helps you.

```
NSString *iPadtext;
NSString *device = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
NSLog(@"deive name is %@",device);
```

Add both images like pause.png and pause-hd.png

```
if([device isEqualToString:@"iPad"] || [device isEqualToString:@"iPad Simulator"] ){
iPadtext = @"-hd";
```

}

```
CCMenuItemImage *pauseMenuItem = [CCMenuItemImage 
                             itemFromNormalImage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pause_01%@.png",iPadText] selectedImage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pause_01-over%@.png",iPadText] 
                             target:self selector:@selector(PauseButtonTapped:)];
```

i hope it will help you